# setInterval function every day, but pass a random integer to another function. So that function fires once every day at a random time

Tags: javascript, date, timer, setinterval, clearinterval

I feel like I am close with this. I want to fire a function at a random point every 24 hours (for testing purposes I am just trying to update every 10 seconds).

Here is my javascript:

```js
let now = new Date();
let rndInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 * 10);

setInterval(function() {
  now = new Date();
  rndInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 * 10);
}, 10 * 1000); // 10 * 1000 milsec

const customTimerFunction = () =>
  setInterval(function() {
    console.log('random int function', now, rndInt)
  }, rndInt);
  
clearInterval(customTimerFunction);

customTimerFunction();
```

As I understand it the anonymous `setInterval` function runs every 10 seconds and updates the `rndInt` variable. This is used by the `customTimerFunction`, but is cleared after each iteration of the function call. When it runs again it should have a new `rndInt` value passed to it.

It seems the `rndInt` value is being updated but the console seems to be logging every 10 seconds, so I assume this is being updated by the regular anonymous `setInterval` function.

I have made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/ksmhgc7p/).

What I want to try and avoid is the custom function running twice in one day.

Any pointers?

**EDIT**

This will be used in a nodejs application, so I can look at using some cron library, although I am not super familiar with cron syntax, but happy to explore that if it is an easy option to integrate.

Comment: Unrelated: `clearInterval` takes a number (the interval Id returned by `setInterval`). You are passing a function as an argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to run at a random point during every 24 hour interval I would have an interval for 24 hours which schedules the function to run at some point in the next 24 hour, i.e.

```js
const myFunction = function() {
  console.log(`I ran at ${new Date().toISOString()}`);
};

const INTERVAL_PERIOD = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

const intervalFunction = function() {
  const nextRunIn = Math.floor(Math.random() * INTERVAL_PERIOD);
  console.log(`The time is ${new Date().toISOString()}, scheduling run at ${new Date(Date.now() + nextRunIn).toISOString()}`);
  setTimeout(myFunction, nextRunIn);
};

setInterval(intervalFunction, INTERVAL_PERIOD);
intervalFunction();
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I actually thought I left a comment of thanks under here, when you posted, but anyways better late than never.